# Two error messages received when accessing or adding entries to Java DB

Tags: java, database

```
    package deadb;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DeaDb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            int controller;
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DeaDornas";
            String uName = "tmybr11";
            String uPass = "1324132448";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY );
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM DeaDornas";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );
            Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
            int beta = 0;
            while( beta == 0 ){
                System.out.printf( "\nCOMPANY'S DATA BASE. WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO?\n" );
                System.out.println( "1 - SEE THE PRODUCTS LIST" );
                System.out.println( "2 - ADD A PRODUCT" );
                System.out.println( "----------" );
                controller = input.nextInt();
                if ( controller == 1 ){
                    while( rs.next() ){
                        String product_name = rs.getString("PRODUCT_NAME");
                        String outtern = "Product: "+ product_name;
                        System.out.println(outtern);
                    }
                } else if ( controller == 2 ){
                    int rowCount = 0;
                    while ( rs.next() ){
                        rowCount++;
                    }
                    int newRow = rowCount + 1;
                    System.out.println( "INFORM THE NAME OF THE PRODUCT:" );
                    String prod = input.next();
                    int c = stmt.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO DeaDornas"
                    + "(ID_PRODUCT, PRODUCT_NAME)"
                    + "VALUES ("+ newRow +", '"+ prod +"')");
                }
            }
        }
        catch( SQLException err ){
            System.out.println( err.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is my main class. I created a database using NetBeans and I'm accessing it using the above application. It works fine if I don't use a while loop. That is, when the user only chooses the option 1 or option 2. But then I added a while loop so the user can either add an entry and see the new entries list after that or see the entries list and add an entry (an endless loop. I will add a way out latter).

This is the output when I add an entry and then see the entries list:

```
COMPANY'S DATA BASE. O QUE DESEJA FAZER?
1 - SEE THE PRODUCTS LIST
2 - ADD A PRODUCT
----------
2
INFORM THE NAME OF THE PRODUCT:
TEST

COMPANY'S DATA BASE. O QUE DESEJA FAZER?
1 - SEE THE PRODUCTS LIST
2 - ADD A PRODUCT
----------
1
O ResultSet não está aberto. A operação 'next' não é permitida. Verifique se a auto-efetivação está desabilitada.
```

So, I didn't found the exact translation (I'm brazilian) for the message above but it's something like "The ResultSet isn't opened. The 'next' operation is not allowed. Check if the auto-effectuation is disabled."

I don't know why that happens and how can I fix this error.

And this is the output when I see the entries list and then add a new entry:

```
COMPANY'S DATA BASE. WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO?
1 - SEE THE PRODUCTS LIST
2 - ADD A PRODUCT
----------
1
Product: RABIT
Product: LYON
Product: CAT
Product: DOG
Product: BIRD
Product: CABELO
Product: TV
Product: FRUIT
Product: FRUIT
Product: ONION
Product: TEST

COMPANY'S DATA BASE. WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO?
1 - SEE THE PRODUCTS LIST
2 - ADD A PRODUCT
----------
2
INFORM THE NAME OF THE PRODUCT:
CARROT
A instrução foi interrompida, porque iria gerar um valor duplicado da chave em uma restrição de chave primária ou de unicidade identificada por 'SQL150619130501560' definida em 'DEADORNAS'.
```

The translation for that would be "The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL150619130501560' defined on 'DEADORNAS'."

So, these are the messages I receive. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is not related to mysql. This code is connecting to a derby database.

Comment: Right. Sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the block for option 1, you need to re execute this query

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );
```

A ResultSet maintains state, and it knows where it is in the table. When it reaches the end, it needs to be repointed to the beginning or you can create a new result set. A result set is like a cursor.

For the second error, it is a little related to the first problem.

```
                    int rowCount = 0;
                    while ( rs.next() ){
                        rowCount++;
                    }
```

Since you are not properly using the resultset, rowCount initializes with a 0 value, then 1 is added to it. Then the insert happens, and it tries to insert a 1 into a index where there is already a one primary key.

Comment: If your program is working, can you mark this question as resolved?